# Android - Styling Spinner within TabView

Tags: java, android, jakarta-ee, spinner, tabview

I've got an app that uses tabs for navigation, and on one of those tabs there is a spinner. However, when the spinner is selected and the actual select window comes up, all the text is white on a white background.
I've tried styling the layout but nothing I do changes the color of the font.

the main class

```
public class RealmsOfWickedry extends TabActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab);

        TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

        TabSpec firstTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid1");
        TabSpec secondTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid1");

        firstTabSpec.setIndicator("Home").setContent(new Intent(this,FirstTab.class));
        secondTabSpec.setIndicator("Catalog").setContent(new Intent(this,SecondTab.class));

        tabHost.addTab(firstTabSpec);
        tabHost.addTab(secondTabSpec);
    }

    public static View makeSpinner(Context context) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.spinner, null);
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        adapter.add("Item 1");
        adapter.add("Item 2");
        adapter.add("Item 3");
        adapter.add("Item 4");
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        return v;
    }
}
```

the class with the spinner

```
public class SecondTab extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /* Second Tab Content */
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText("Choose a Category");
        setContentView(textView);
        setContentView(RealmsOfWickedry.makeSpinner(getParent())); 
    }
}
```

tab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TabHost android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></TabWidget>
        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

spinner.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Spinner 
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:prompt="@string/cat_prompt"
        android:theme="@style/DropdownStyle"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

themes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="OverallStyle" parent="@android:Theme.Light">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bg</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>
    <style name="WelcomeStyle" parent="@android:Theme.Light">
        <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    </style>
    <style name="CustomStyle" parent="@android:Theme.Light">
        <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">top</item>
    </style>
    <style name="DropdownStyle" parent="@android:Theme.Light">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Are you using a manufacturer UI or Google? What code creates the dialog?

Comment: I'm only using Google's APIs. the line that creates the spinner is `setContentView(RealmsOfWickedry.makeSpinner(getParent()));` which is defined in the main class

Comment: Specifically Manufacturer theme, such Sense, Touch Wiz, Blur, Google?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure. I'm still a noob when it comes to Java and Android. I would assume Google since I didn't add any third-party add-ons or anything.

Comment: The virtual device emulator. I haven't added the pkg to my actual device yet.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to override the system theme to show a different color which is the right path to be on. Your spinner xml contains a reference to `android:theme` I haven't see that one before and it doesn't appear to be part of the API for this widget. To get your DropdownStyle to work, first, add it as part of your OverallStyle style with an item name of `@android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle`. Second, change DropdownStyle's parent to `@android:Widget.DropDownItem.Spinner`. I'm assuming that OverallStyle is applied to the Activity or Application in the Manifest already. This will change the style for all Spinner drop down Items.

To apply only to this view's drop down items do only step two above then add `style="@style/OverallStyle"` to the spinner in its layout.

Additional Information:

```
<style name="DropdownStyle" parent="@android:Widget.DropDownItem.Spinner">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
</style>
<style name="OverallStyle" parent="@android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bg</item>
    <item name="@android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/DropdownStyle</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

**-OR-**

themes.xml

```
<style name="DropdownStyle" parent="@android:Widget.DropDownItem.Spinner">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
</style>
```

spinner.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Spinner 
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:prompt="@string/cat_prompt"
        style="@style/DropdownStyle"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "add [DropdownStyle] as part of your OverallStyle style with the name of...". Could you provide a syntax example?